# max poll records in kafka are getting changed over subsequent polls

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

2 producers are producing similar kind of message to a single-partitioned topic. Messages are similar in terms of size(~700KB) and structure. Each producer sends 500 messages.

After 1st producer has sent all messages, the consumer is able to receive all 500 messages in a single poll(). Hypothetically, After 2nd producer has sent messages, the consumer should also receive 500 messages in a single poll(). But, it only read 100 messages in each poll().

Why do consumer acts differently for different producers?

My consumer is configured with the following parameter.

```
max.poll.records=500
fetch.max.bytes=500000000
```

Comment: How many consumers you have? And how many consumer groups you have?

Comment: A kafka consumer have a local buffer. If buffer fills up or fetch.max.wait.ms reached then send all of the buffered messages. https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs

Comment: I have only one consumer running at a time and I make sure to publish all messages on topic before consuming it.

Comment: 0 min - start broker; 5 min - start producer; 10 min - start consumer; 15 min - start new producer; 20 min - start new consumer. If you perform experiment like that then most likely you should see the same result.